# Are there (many) weak verbs with ei or ie in the stem?

Tags: verb, conjugation

I have seen lists of stem-changing verbs, and a large group of those are verbs with ei or ie in the stem.

Is the presence of those two-letter combinations an automatic indicator that the verb is stem-changing?

I came across *meinen*, so there´s at least one.  Is that the exception, or the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many verbs with /ie/ or /ei/ are strong verbs, mostly belonging to either class I (infinitive with /ei/, e.g. *bleiben*) or class II (infinitive with /ie/, e.g. *fliegen*), but not all verbs with /ie/ or /ei/ are strong.

Examples for weak verbs with /ie/: siegen, quieken.

Example for a weak verb with /ei/: zeigen.